# Javascript function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an animated menu that functions on the outward but it's stuck on the way back, the first (#section-1) returns perfectly but not other two (#section2, & #section3) sections. Can anybody help me?

```
$(function() {
    var outTranslate = {
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        '-moz-transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        '-o-transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        'transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        'opacity': '0'
    };

    $("span.menu").click(function() {
        $("#section-1").css(outTranslate, function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#section-2").css(outTranslate);
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#section-3").css(outTranslate);
            }, 200);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#menu-overlay").fadeOut(750, 'easeOutQuad');
            }, 300);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to put your code on JsFiddle

Comment: Please show the HTML as well, and clarify what the problem is (what does "stuck on the way back" mean?)

Comment: `.css()` doesn't have default callback .

Comment: There isn't a `.css()` method that includes a function callback on completion. This would be obvious if you [read the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: Why dont you add a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot callback function after setting css properties. Because it's not async to have callback. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var outTranslate = {
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        '-moz-transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        '-o-transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        'transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        'opacity': '0'
    };

    $("span.menu").click(function() {
        $("#section-1").css(outTranslate);
        setTimeout(function() {$("#section-2").css(outTranslate);}, 100);
        setTimeout(function() {$("#section-3").css(outTranslate);}, 200);
        setTimeout(function() {$("#menu-overlay").fadeOut(750, 'easeOutQuad');}, 300);
    });
});
```

or this (using transition framework) (link: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/):

```
$(function() {
    var outTranslate = {
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        '-moz-transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        '-o-transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        'transform': 'translateX(-100%)',
        'opacity': '0'
    };

    $("span.menu").click(function() {
        $("#section-1").transition(outTranslate, function(){
            setTimeout(function() {$("#section-2").css(outTranslate);}, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {$("#section-3").css(outTranslate);}, 200);
            setTimeout(function() {$("#menu-overlay").fadeOut(750, 'easeOutQuad');}, 300);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant, functioned perfectly. Thanks so much numßer ! So I didn't need the function on the first (#section-1)